# Trying to set an object to true or false using a variable in java

Tags: java, object, boolean

So I am refactoring some very old code, and I see the same code repeated about 20 times the only difference is that the object being set to true or false is changing.

I'm trying to figure out how to set the object using .notation to set it to true or false.

it looks something like this.

```
if("true".equals(this.element.getText())) {
    endorse.setFDSC(true);
}else {
    endorse.setFDSC(false);
}
```

my current method looks like this.

```
private void setEndorsmentRecordsToF( EndorsementRecordApplication endorse, String location) throws Exception {

     if("true".equals(this.element.getText())) {
         endorse.setFDSC(true);
     }else {
         endorse.setFDSC(false);
     }
}
```

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated, each one of these objects are different but the same logic applies.

Comment: It's hard to understand your issue without seeing the entire code. However, this: `endorse.setFDSC("true".equalsIgnoreCase(this.element.getText()));` is much shorter than the if-else condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static methods of `Boolean.class`. So you can use `Boolean.parseBoolean` method. And then your code will be like this;

```
private void setEndorsmentRecordsToF(EndorsementRecordApplication endorse, String location) throws Exception {
    endorse.setFDSC(Boolean.parseBoolean(this.element.getText()));
}
```

In `Boolean.class` this methods body is ;

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String var0) {
    return var0 != null && var0.equalsIgnoreCase("true");
}
```

So checking with **equalsIgnoreCase**.

If you want to **convert boolean value to String** , use this method already defined in `Boolean.class`;

```
public static String toString(boolean var0) {
    return var0 ? "true" : "false";
}
```